# How to create SessionFactory using Hibernate4 and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I am having issues trying to manage hibernate to work with spring. I don't know how to initiate a Session class on my code. NetBeans keep me saying that the variable sessionFactory has not been initialized.
The problem I am having is on HibernateTest.java when I try sessionFactory.openSession();

Here is the structure of the project and the code, I hope you can help me, thank you.
PS. I am using NetBeans 8.0.1

Structure (Dont have rep to upload an image so ill copy as it follows):
-Hibernate Course
    +Web Pages
    -Source Packages
        -com.course.entity
            Gender.java
      -com.source.test
            HibernateTest.java
    -Other Sources
        -src/main/resources
        -<>default package<>
              hibernate.cfg.xml
              spring.xml
    +Dependencies
    +Java Dependencies
    +Project files

spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.3.xsd">

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="userDao" class="com.course.entity.Gender">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>    
</beans>
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Hibernate</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="com.course.entity.Gender"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Gender.java

```
package com.course.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
public class Gender {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ggender_cod_seq", initialValue = 0)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gender_cod_seq", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int codeGender;

    private String gender;

    public int getCodeGender() {
        return codeGender;
    }

    public void setCodeGender(int codeGender) {
        this.codeGender = codeGender;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    } 
}
```

HibernateTest.java

```
package com.source.test;

import com.course.entity.Gender;
import java.text.ParseException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        Gender gender = new Gender();

        gender.setCodeGender(3);

        gender.setGender("Test");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(gender);

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are not using spring at all in your example, because `main` in `HibernateTest` does not try to bootstrap a Spring application context.

What happens is simply that you *declare* a hibernate session factory, do not initialize it, and try to use it. So yes Netbeans is right, variable `sessionFactory` is never initialized in your code.

To fix it, you must first choose whether you want to directly use Hibernate and then read and follow a Hibernate tutorial, of use Spring + Hibernate and read and follow a Spring tutorial.

The tutorial form Hibernate manual recommends to use an util class similar to :

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

and use it to create the Hibernate session factory. But again this does not use Spring.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am planning to use Spring so then I can have just one SessionFactory for the whole program, as SessionFactory demands so much resources of the system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject SessionFatory as a spring-managed bean with [@Autowired](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) or get it from the Spring application context:

```
public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = context.getBean("sessionFactory", SessionFactory.class);

        Gender gender = new Gender();
        gender.setCodeGender(3);
        gender.setGender("Test");      

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(gender);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Also, you can use [@Transational](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) instead of manual transaction management.